# How to fix footer in the end of the page?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm trying to fix the footer at the bottom of the page but I can't do that. I've already tried a lot of solutions that I found here on StackOverflow and other websites but none of them worked.

What I have right now is a sticky footer.

Here is the footer html (the footer tag is inside the body tag)

```css
/*BODY*/

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
  padding: 0;
}


/*FOOTER*/

#footer-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 12.5px;
  width: 61px;
  height: 25px;
}

.master-footer-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.master-footer-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.master-footer-list a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.master-footer-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer {
  font-family: var(--work-sans);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer div {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

footer a {
  color: #FF6869;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer span {
  color: #C8C7CC;
}
```

```html
<footer>

  <div class="master-footer-wrap">
    <a href="/"><img id="footer-logo" src="/assets/images/logo-white.png" /></a>
    <ul class="master-footer-list">
      <li><span>© 2019 – iStudi. Todos os direitos reservados.</span></li>
      <li><a href="/termos-de-uso">Termos de Uso</a></li>
      <li><a href="/politica-de-privacidade">Política de Privacidade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</footer>
```

Comment: If possible, you may try to use ready made solution like : https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Comment: What do you mean by *fix the footer*?

Comment: A footer that stays on the bottom of the webpage no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a `master-footer-wrap` and the `footer` itself set to position fixed. However, you need to set the `position: relative` for the body and to `absolute` for the footer. If you do this while either the `footer` or the `master-footer-wrap` is still set to `position: fixed`, it will remain fixed. Check the snippet below for a working example :)

```css
/*BODY*/

html, body {
  position: relative;
  height: 150%;
  margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

/*FOOTER*/

#footer-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 12.5px;
  width: 61px;
  height: 25px;
}

.master-footer-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.master-footer-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.master-footer-list a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* removed master footer wrap css */

footer {
  font-family: var(--work-sans);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute; /* position absolute instead of fixed */
  bottom: -50px; /* move inside the body margin */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Removed redundant div/wrapper */

footer a {
  color: #FF6869;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer span {
  color: #C8C7CC;
}
```

```html
<footer>

    <a href="/"><img id="footer-logo" src="/assets/images/logo-white.png"><a/>
      <ul class="master-footer-list">
        <li><span>© 2019 – iStudi. Todos os direitos reservados.</span></li>
        <li><a href="/termos-de-uso">Termos de Uso</a></li>
        <li><a href="/politica-de-privacidade">Política de Privacidade</a></li>
      </ul>

</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but it's a litte below the end of the page (I tried changing the body `height` from 150% to 100% but the footer went to the middle of the page. Here is how it looks like now: https://i.imgur.com/2UcHkbs.png
If you want to see it live or check the code/css, you can go to http://www.istudi.com.br

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution is to use flexbox. Here is a working fiddle using the Tailwind library:

```
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <header class="h-8 bg-red">

  </header>
  <main class="flex-1">
     The main content
  </main>
  <footer class="h-8 bg-green">

  </footer>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nartub/b4fwg3um/

Classes are self-explanatory but you can refer to the Tailwind docs to see what each class does.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS can be greatly simplified. You don't need all of those banners and wrappers. Simply set `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` and remove the padding at the bottom of the page, and your footer will stick.

There must be some way to get rid of that hardcoded `#footer-logo` stuff that makes the text overlap the logo when the width gets thin, but I can't figure it out.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

footer {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #C8C7CC;
  background-color: black;

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 50px;  /* improved support for narrow screens */
  width: 100%;
}

#footer-logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 12.5px;
  width: 61px;
  height: 25px;
}

footer a {
  color: #FF6869;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <a href="#"><img id="footer-logo" src="//stackexchange.com/users/flair/6784526.png" /></a>
    <ul>
      <li> 2019 — wizzwizz4</li>
      <li><a href="#">Lovely link</a></li>
      <li><a href="//stackoverflow.com">Visited link</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```